# Chat script that allows anonymous visitors to chat with one of registered users

Tags: chat, messaging, anonymous, instant, visitors

I have a classified ads website where I have users registered through my MySQL database. Now I want to integrate a chat that anonymous visitors can use to chat with the user about the user's ad. For every visitor the user needs one chat room, so maybe a Facebook-Like chat for the user would be nice.

Can somebody tell me if there's a free script out there which has all these features or the most of them ?

Answer (score 0):

We are using https://chatpocket.com, it has android app which inform about new messages, you can have several website on one account. It is free, also for commecial use.